# How to split numpy array into single values?

Tags: python, numpy

So I currently have a numpy array like

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

but I want it to be

```
[[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

Is there a list comprehension method to do so?

Comment: a.reshape(-1, 1)

Answer (score 3):

Using either [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) or translate [`T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) you can do:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])

a.reshape(a.size, 1)
```

or

```
a.T
```

With the result being:

```
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first array can be created by

```
array1 = np.arange(5).reshape((1,5))
```

Printing `array1` gives

```
[[0 1 2 3 4]]
```

You can reshape that with

```
array2 = array1.reshape((5,1))
```

Printing that gives

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]
```

Or, as @LucaCappelletti typed before I could,

```
array2 = array1.T
```

That `T` means "transpose," swapping the columns and the rows of a 2-dimensional matrix. This is simpler but is more error-prone if `array1` is not just what you think it is. Yet another way is

```
array2 = array1.transpose()
```

which is basically a synonym for `T`.

Answer (score 0):

I heard you say **list comprehension** :) Here you go

```
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
a_new = [[i] for i in a[0]]
print (a_new)
```

Comment: Who is downvoting the solution which the OP asked for specifically. If it's about `list` versus `array` definition of `a`, that's no reason to downvote. Downvoting without reasoning is just immature. OP clearly asked for *list comprehension method*